# My image link extends beyond the image...?

Tags: image, hyperlink

The "Time to choose" button here has a link that extends beyond the image (http://www.ecoculturevillage.org/coolstuff/)

```
.image-1 {
    width: 255px;
    height: 75px;
    display: block;
    background-image: url();
}

.image-1:hover {
    background-image: url();
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.urchinsky.com" target="_blank">
    <div class="image-1" ></div>
</a>
<div class="clearfloat"></div>
```

Comment: Why not use a real image? `<a><img /></a>`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have wrapped a block level element inside the link, here is a solution for that. Replace `display: block` with `display: table-cell`

```
.image-1 {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Great but make sure you use a `span` element instead of `div` when wrapping inside `a`. Currently all browsers don't support it.